# Faster approach to transform a bunch of .csv file into HDF dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, netcdf, hdf

#### 1. Background

HDF is a superb file format  for data storage and management.

I have a source data (365 `.csv` files) which containing the air quality data (*time resolution 1h*) for all monitoring sites (*more than 1500*) of China. Each file is consisted of many feature (particulate matter, SO2, etc) and its corresponding time.

I have uploaded some template files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQMHFvOEF3QUY0cUE) for someone interested.

> **My goal ==> Merge all the files into one dataframe for efficient management**

#### 2. My code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
#coding=utf-8
import pandas as pd
from pandas import HDFStore, DataFrame
from pandas import read_hdf

import os,sys,string
import numpy as np

### CREAT A EMPTY HDF5 FILE

hdf = HDFStore("site_2016_whole_year.h5")


### READ THE CSV FILES AND SAVE IT INTO HDF5 FORMAT
os.chdir("./site_2016/")
files = os.listdir("./")
files.sort()

### Read an template file to get the name of columns    
test_file= "china_sites_20160101.csv"
test_f = pd.read_csv(test_file,encoding='utf_8')
site_columns = list(test_f.columns[3:])
print site_columns[1]

feature =  ['pm25','pm10','O3','O3_8h','CO',"NO2",'SO2',"aqi"]
fe_dict = {"pm25":1,"aqi":0, 'pm10':3, 'SO2':5,'NO2':7, 'O3':9,"O3_8h":11, "CO": 13}
for k in range(0,len(feature),1):
    data_2016 = {"date":[],'hour':[],}
    for i in range(0,len(site_columns),1):
        data_2016[site_columns[i]] = []
    for file in files[0:]:
        filename,extname = os.path.splitext(file)
        if (extname == ".csv"):
            datafile =file
            f_day = pd.read_csv(datafile,encoding='utf_8')
            site_columns = list(f_day.columns[3:])
            for i in range(0,len(f_day),15):
                datetime = str(f_day["date"].iloc[i])
                hour = "%02d" % ((f_day["hour"].iloc[i]))
                data_2016["date"].append(datetime)
                data_2016["hour"].append(hour)
                for t in range(0,len(site_columns),1): 
                    data_2016[site_columns[t]].\
                  append(f_day[site_columns[t]].iloc[i+fe_dict[feature[k]]])]
  data_2016  = pd.DataFrame(data_2016)
  hdf.put(feature[k], data_2016, format='table', encoding="utf-8")
```

#### 3. My problem

Using my code above, the hdf5 file can be created but with slow speed.

My lab has a Linux cluster with 32 core CPU. Is there any method to transform my program into multi-processing ones?

Answer (score 1):

maybe I do not understand your problem properly, but I would use something like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

indir = <'folder with downloaded 12 csv files'>
indata = []
for i in os.listdir(indir):
    indata.append(pd.read_csv(indir + i))

out_table = pd.concat(indata)
hdf = pd.HDFStore("site_2016_whole_year.h5", complevel=9, complib='blosc')
hdf.put('table1',out_table)
hdf.close()
```

for 12 input files it takes 2.5 sec on my laptop, so even for 365 files it should be done in a minute or so. I do not see need for parallelisation in this case.